# unable to view image taken from camera using fileURI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

i am using angular 4/Ionic4.i need to send image to database using file_URI not data_URL because data URL is encoded in base64 which is taking too much memory. initially i used base64 which is totally fine and working but my senior told me to do the same with FILE_uri and i am struggling for 2 days to display image and send it to the database.i tried normalizing-URL,domsanitizer,web-view but didn't work.check if upload() code is correct to send image to database

```html
 <img [src]="image"/>
```

```
 image:any;
 take(){
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false

   }

  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
// this.success = 'getting image is successful';
this.image =imageData;
// this.imageURI = this.webview.convertF(imageData);
  }, (err) => {
 this.err = err;
 });
}

upload(){
  let url="https://staging-api.kofluence.com/influencer/v1/profile";
  let postData=new FormData();
  postData.append('file',this.image);
  let data:Observable<any>=this.http.post(url,postData);
  data.subscribe((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
  }
  );
}
```

Comment: try here [LINK](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/) then search for  "The Basics for Our Image Upload" and "Adding New Images".
"we are not using a base64 as a result but the real FILE_URI of the image", is this what are you lookin' for?

Comment: yes.can u please post code for my thing.

Comment: honestly I can't, I never use Ionic so probably I would make you wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Displaying image source from fileURI in ionic**

Did you tried webview ?

if not please try below steps, ionic doesn't display the images with file://.. it should be localhost://.. something.

so that install webview package and Convert a file:// URL to a URL that is compatible with the local web server in the Web View plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
npm install @ionic-native/ionic-webview
```

**usage :**

```
import { WebView } from '@ionic-native/ionic-webview/ngx';

constructor(private webview: WebView) { }

  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

this.image =this.webview.convertFileSrc(imageData);

  }, (err) => {
 this.err = err;
 });
```

**2. Upload file blob to server**

first you have to convert file to blob and then append to the formData.

**Note: keep in mind here this.image is string of the file path its not a exact file.**

**upload:**

We have to convert image to blob file and then send it to server.

```
upload(){
  let url="https://staging-api.kofluence.com/influencer/v1/profile";

 const blobValue = this.dataURItoBlob(this.image);

  let postData=new FormData();
  postData.append('file',blobValue);

  let data:Observable<any>=this.http.post(url,postData);
  data.subscribe((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
  }
  );
```

**Convert dataUri to blob**

```
 private dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    let byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    let mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    let arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    let _ia = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      _ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    let dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
    let blob = new Blob([dataView], { type: mimeString });
    return blob;
  }
```

Please let me know if we face any issues with this code.

Comment: keyword private giving error saying that 'Declaration or expected statement'.

Comment: can u please share your complete code, u have to put this method (private dataURItoBlob(dataURI)) out side of the upload method.

Comment: the thing is i should upload it as a file not blob.my colleague even if i upload it as blob they need to convert it to base64 and into file to display to image.

Comment: i did not understand what is the exact issue here, i think we cant send directly a file in http request. we have to save image as blob in the server and send / receive like bolb only if you cant able to display blob then you have to convert to base64.

Comment: thanks jack i am just beginner i dont know much about this.so i discussed the same issue with my senior he told that he will look into it.

Comment: thanks, @PremKumar  feel free to ask any questions here, if this answer is helpful to you please mark it as answer.